# State Space Representation for Initial Conditions

Tags: capacitor, control, state-space

I am trying to design a system in which a capacitor's current discharge into an inductor is controlled by a MOSFET. I am trying to use a closed-loop control system to control the MOSFET's Vgs, and thereby the current through the RLC loop. Because the capacitor is initially charged to some voltage, I cannot not use transfer function analysis because the initial conditions are non-zero. With non-zero initial conditions, is state space analysis the best method to design the control parameters? A simple diagram is featured below. [image]